# Why set variable to !1 instead of false?

Tags: javascript

Looking at some JavaScript code and wondering why someone would do this:
`var x = !1;`
instead of:
`var x = false;`

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: I personally prefer to write `!7`, which is much more aesthetic

Answer (score 0):

Is it minified code?  The goal of minified code is to convey the same logic while minimizing the file/transfer size.  In that case, `!1` is only two bytes vs. `false`, which is 5 bytes.

Comment: so, `!0` is `true`...;)

Comment: Completely forgot about this question. @Matt Huggins: it was not minified, but it did cross my mind that could be why.